# How to get SignalR working with Suave?

Tags: f#, signalr, suave

Does anyone have an example of how to get SignalR working in Suave?

I've created a [demo project](https://gist.github.com/aaron-comyn/c9c44a029c05e866018fd42b412efae2) showing a working Suave server, and working hub proxy generation, along with with a demo page.  The page shows a failed initialization and repeated errors attempting to connect to "//ping".

Server configuration:

```
    let app =
    choose [
             GET >=>
                choose [
                    path "/demo" >=> file (Files.resolvePath __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ "test.html")
                    OwinApp.ofAppFunc "/" SignalServer.app
                ]
            ]

    startWebServer defaultConfig app
```

The issue seems to be routing all the signalR 'plumbing' (pings and websockets), appropriately through Suave, but I've had no luck with that so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Should be fixed via https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/pull/548

---

This seems like a bug in Suave's Owin implementation.  You should report it to the repo.

I do have hack fix, but requires compiling Suave yourself.    https://github.com/TheAngryByrd/suave/tree/signalrdemo

Comment: @Aaron Winston Comyn poking someone (i.e. all) at https://gitter.im/SuaveIO/suave did get a response. youre welcome ;-)